# Create page index -Xslt 1.0 -

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my XML:

```
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
            <REGION>10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia</REGION>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>0840</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
            <REGION>10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia</REGION>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>0843</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>        
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
            <REGION>10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia</REGION>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>0850</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>        
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
            <REGION>16-Mar Tirreno - Francia (Corsica)</REGION>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>0906</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
            <REGION>16-Mar Tirreno - Francia (Corsica)</REGION>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>0922.15</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
            <REGION>25-Mare Adriatico - Slovenia</REGION>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3620</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST>
```

This is my XSLT 1.0:

```
<table style='border-collapse:collapse;  width:100%; align:center' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER">
    <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" data-type="text"/>                                           
        <tr style="line-height:0.78cm">
            <xsl:variable name="regione" select="preceding-sibling::REGION"/>
            <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">
                <xsl:if test="following::REGION != $regione">
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::REGION"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </td>

            <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

This create a table in two column. In the first column write Region and in the second column write ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER.

10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia   0840
10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia   0843
10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia   0850
16-Mar Tirreno - Francia (Corsica)  0906
16-Mar Tirreno - Francia (Corsica)  0922.15
25-Mare Adriatico - Slovenia    3620

But I want this output:

10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia       0840 - 0850
16-Mar Tirreno - Francia (Corsica)       0906 - 0922.15
25-Mare Adriatico - Slovenia                       3620

Pratically: write the first region and the first ITA_LIGHT_NAME, if the following REGION is different from the current write the ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. To learn how to do this in XSLT 1.0, see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Then do a search for questions tagged `XSLT 1.0` and `grouping` to find numerous examples.

Comment: Can you help me michael.hor257k. Thanks. Can I do this without use key?

Comment: It can be done without using a key but the key-based approaches are likely to be significantly more efficient to run. Why the restriction, out of interest? Keys are supported by every processor I've ever used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's much better if you use keys.

Define it for example at the beginning of your XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="lightproducts" match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT" use="REGION"/>
```

And you might modify your template as follows:

```
  <table style='border-collapse:collapse;  width:100%; align:center' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <xsl:for-each select="//NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT">
          <xsl:sort select="REGION" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
          <xsl:variable name="regione" select="REGION" />

          <xsl:if test="not(preceding::NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT[REGION/text() = $regione])">
              <tr style="line-height:0.78cm">
                  <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$regione"/>
                  </td>
                  <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">
                      <xsl:for-each select="key('lightproducts', $regione)">
                          <xsl:sort select="ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                          <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="last() = 1">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                                  <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                                  <xsl:value-of select="ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                              </xsl:when>
                          </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

This is what I obtain with your input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;  width:100%; align:center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr style="line-height:0.78cm">
      <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">10-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Francia</td>
      <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">0840-0850</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="line-height:0.78cm">
      <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">16-Mar Tirreno - Francia (Corsica)</td>
      <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">0906-0922.15</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="line-height:0.78cm">
      <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">25-Mare Adriatico - Slovenia</td>
      <td style="height:0.68cm;border-bottom:dotted 1.0">3620</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Frik if this answer solves your problem, please accept it. Thnx!

Comment: Thanks potame's I try it tomorrow... but i think it work. Thanks.